# How to admin other users on an Amplify app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In a React Amplify app, I am waiting to build an admin page for some users to be able to manage and update the attributes of the other users. looking at the API page for the Auth classes https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html I am not seeing that kind of capability. To me it would seem that there would be some sort of API for an Admin user to manage other users. If anyone has any guidance.